# RegExp - How to check if a string contains a substring in the certain position?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to search this question first but didn't found what I need, here is it:

I have a string like: "substring1/substring2.substring3" (e.g. "library/History.read")

I need a regular expression to check:

1. the substring1 must be "library"
2. the substring2 must have a captial letter at the beginning
3. the substring3 must be "read"

I'm not familiar with regular expression, the current I wrote is:
`'library/([a-zA-Z])\\.(read)'`  but it is not correct. Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to solve regex problems, starting from your own attempt here's something that works! :-)

```
library/([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+)\.(read)
```

You had three small mistakes:

- `.` is a character class matching any character except newline. Escape your `.` like this `\.` not like this `\\.`; and
- Your first capture group was matching exactly one letter. You missed the quantifier. Use the `+` qunatifier to match one or more.
- As pointed out by Peter, you were missing a character class for your first capital letter

Comment: Glad it helped! :-) Will you consider marking my question as the accepted answer? I'm new here I hope to get some reputation.

Comment: @Meilan I noticed you marked the other answer as accepted (in case it was a mistake...) Thanks!

Comment: Actually the regex does not account for initial caps letter. Should be `library/([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)\.(read)`

Comment: Correct Peter! I only focused on the reason is regex wasn't matching instead of the requirements. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```js
testStrings = ["library/History.read", "library/other.read", "library/Geography.read", "library/History.unread", "ebook/hstory.read", "library/StackOverflow.read"]
regex = /library\/[A-Z][^\.]*\.read/

testStrings.forEach(testString => {
  console.log(regex.test(testString) + " - " + testString)
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I run this regex on the online compiler with the following code, but all of them return false, do you know why? https://rextester.com/l/js_online_compiler ```

Comment: ```
const testStrings = ["library/History.read", "library/other.read", "library/Geography.read", "library/History.unread", "ebook/hstory.read", "library/StackOverflow.read"];

const pattern = new RegExp('/library\/[A-Z][^\.]*\.read/')

for (var index = 0; index < 6; index++){
    print(testStrings[index]);
    print(pattern.test(testStrings[index]));
}
```

Comment: @Meilan: That online tool seems to support only older JavaScript. Change function call to: `testStrings.forEach(function(testString) { ...`. Also, change `console.log()` to `print()`

Comment: The code does not work because you have to remove the `/` like `const pattern = new RegExp('library\/[A-Z][^.]*\.read');` or remove the `'` and keep the `/`. In that case, you can use `const pattern = /library\/[A-Z][^.]*\.read/;`

Comment: Off topic, but don't concat different values into a single string like that when you `log` them. Especially not different types. They may look the same in the output from the SO snippets, but not in the console. `true`, `"true"` and `[true]` are not the same thing, but will be serialized the same way. Check this: `console.log(true + "," + "true" + "," + [true, true])` vs `console.log(true, "true", [true, true])` Or [use string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Using_string_substitutions): `console.log("match: %o - %o", regex.test(testString), testString)`